How to mount /dev separatedly in OpenBSD?
All partitions can have: "rw,nodev,nosuid", only exception is the "/dev" directory (that it cannot have "nodev").
Is there a way that i can partition a new OpenBSD install that all usual mounts would be under "/", with the only exception of "/dev"?
So there should be two partitions: "/" and "/dev" - is this possible?

Yes it is, but... why?

for storage efficiency. why having many partitions when they are using the same mount option? only /dev using different mount option as it needs dev files. logs will not fill up the /.

They don't necessarily have the same mount options. You probably want noexec on /var, or /tmp, but not on /usr or /. You might need wxallowed on /usr/local but not anywhere else, etc etc etc. Logs will not fill up / until they do, and then you'll be screwed if you can't even log in. There are plenty of reasons for using separate mount points, and, in an age where virtually any storage medium has at least 16Gb, efficiency is definitely not a problem, IMHO.

"Yes it is, but... why? – Zé Loff" -> no, afaik you cannot separate /dev, since it won't boot anymore. looks like OpenBSD always wants the /dev inside the "/" - @ZéLoff

why cannot i have noexec on /usr ?

Because you (almost certainly) need the binaries on /usr/bin.

/dev uses around 40kB on OpenBSD 7.5, of which ~12kB go to the MAKEDEV script, so there really is no need to have it as a separate partition. It is the directory holding just the device pseudofiles (plus the mentioned script, and a few lockfiles).

no, afaik you cannot separate /dev, since it won't boot anymore. looks like OpenBSD always wants the /dev inside the "/" - this looks like an answer to the question.

The only possible reason behind having /dev as a separate partition would be to prevent a mistake like dd if=install-disk.img of=/dev/sda (note that OpenBSD does not have the device named sda), which would create a regular file named /dev/sda, potentially several GB in size. The real solution is to be more careful when executing any commands as root, especially one such as that. Also, command line completion (Tab key) helps.
